# Changing value of Java enum in debugger in Eclipse?

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to force this expression in the if statement to be true in debugging:

```
enumFooValue = getValue()
if (enumFooValue == Foo.BAR)
```

However, the value returned by getValue() is not Foo.BAR but Foo.BAZ. I have tried changing enumFooValue in the Eclipse debugger by changing the name to BAR and the ordinal value but this does not seem to work. I read that equality between an enum and another enum requires that the two objects be equal. Not sure how to proceed since I do not know the id of Foo.BAR if that is what is required.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: You do not try to change the ordinal or the name but the whole thing to Foo.BAR.

Answer (score 0):

On the Debug perspective go to the Variables view, choose your variable and in the context menu choose "Change value ..." item.

It will open the window where you can write code like `MyEnum.ENUM_CONSTANT`.